# Download Apple-hosted content for free product (in-app purchase) on first run without sign in

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, iap-hosted-content

Is it possible to download Apple-hosted content for free product  (in-app purchase)  on first run without sign in to iTunes.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. IAP content, free or not, requires the user to validate their purchase through the manual purchase process. You cannot do it invisibly.